# How to reference controls located on different Tabs VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, tabcontrol

Looking to reference a Data Grid view on another Tab that is create by code.

I want to populate the combo box with the columns of the data grid view that is in the currently selected tab. Right now i can only get the combo box to populate with the last file loaded by the user, not w/e tab is selected.

```
Dim mstrFirstFile As String = ""
Dim mstrFileName As String = ""
Dim mdstTableInput As New DataSet
Dim mintCounter As Integer
Dim mdgvTab As DataGridView

Public Function CreateNewDGVInsideNewPageTab() As DataGridView
    Dim tbpNewTab As New TabPage()
    tbpNewTab.Text = mstrFileName

    Dim mdgvTabControl As New DataGridView
    mdgvTabControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    mdgvTabControl.Name = ("Grid" + ToString(mintCounter))

    tbpNewTab.Controls.Add(mdgvTabControl)
    tbcsource.TabPages.Add(tbpNewTab)
    tbcsource.SelectedTab = tbpNewTab
    Return mdgvTabControl
End Function

Private Sub generate()

    Dim objCLSConverter As New DataTier.clsCSVConverter
    Dim strNewXMLPath As String = ""
    Dim xmlFile As XmlReader

    If mstrFirstFile.Length > 1 Then


        strNewXMLPath = objCLSConverter.writeXML(mstrFirstFile)

        xmlFile = XmlReader.Create(strNewXMLPath, New XmlReaderSettings())

        Dim dsTemp As DataSet = New DataSet
        Dim dtTable As DataTable = Nothing

        dsTemp.ReadXml(xmlFile)
        dtTable = dsTemp.Tables(0).Copy
        dtTable.TableName = mintCounter
        mdstTableInput.Tables.Add(dtTable)

        mdgvTab = CreateNewDGVInsideNewPageTab()

        mdgvTab.DataSource = mdstTableInput.Tables(mintCounter)

        mintCounter = (mintCounter + 1)

        cbxColumnsUpdate()

        xmlFile.Close()

    End If
End Sub
```

Any help or if you need more of my code let me know.

---

The program takes any .csv or .xls file a user adds and tosses it into dataset. It adds these files onto a new code generated Tab with a data grid view inside that has the file loaded into it.

When a tab is selected a combo box will be populated with all the column names of that tabs data grid view, you can select any of the tabs and it will repopulate the combo box for that tab. You can then select from the combo box the column name and then in a text box enter w/e you are searching for in that column, its just a select where clause.

This data will then be tosses into a data grid view below for the user to see and export to excel or continue to change. This is all for general reporting purposes and massaging of data.

Right now the problem is that the combo box won't repopulated based on the tab selected.

Comment: If at design time, control should be available at form level. At runtime, every tab control has tag pages in it. Just reference TabPage.Controls.

Comment: Got a example of this for me ? Not that great with coding : P. Then trying to reference the data grid view inside of that tab seems a bit tricky to join them.

Comment: With little detail, it's hard to tell exactly. One option is using `mdgvTab.Controls("Grid" + ToString(mintCounter))`, but it's better that you keep a `Dictionary of (ToString(mintCounter), DataGridView)`. Do you need example of Dictionary usage?

Comment: Any and all examples are nice to have : )

Comment: See my answer - hope it helps.

Comment: Regarding your update, it certainly clarifies certain things. But why would you repopulate the combo box every time a tab is selected? From your edit, the tab will contain a data grid with a fixed list of columns, coming from the file. Why reload the combo box? Also, do you mean that until user selects a filter, the grid is empty? All in all, it sounds like MS Excel would work best for your need, i.e. no point to write a .NET program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an option - convert this:

```
Dim mdgvTab As DataGridView
```

to a dictionary:

```
Dim mdgvTabDictionary As Dictionary(Of Integer, DataGridView)
```

Then, inside `Sub generate()` you replace this:

```
mdgvTab = CreateNewDGVInsideNewPageTab()
```

to this:

```
Dim mdgvTab As DataGridView = CreateNewDGVInsideNewPageTab()
mdgvTabDictionary.Add(mintCounter, mdgvTab)
```

Now you don't need to deal with control hierarchy and find controls by name. Instead, you can find the `DataGridView` you need by index: `mdgvTabDictionary(index)`.

Don't forget to initialize `mdgvTabDictionary` at `Sub New`, `Form_Load` (or any other place, as applicable to your situation):

```
mdgvTabDictionary = New Dictionary(Of Integer, DataGridView)
```

Comment: Getting the error "given key was not present in the dictionary", when i try use `strColNames(i) = mdgvTabDictionary(mintCounter).Columns(i).Name`  Never used dictionary so its a little strange for me.

Comment: @Xnub: If you incremented `mintCounter`, which you do as one of the last statements of `generate`, it will be equal to `(x+1)`, where `x` is the maximum key in the dictionary, and of course, this key is not present in it. You need to know which index you will be accessing, before doing it. I mentioned `mintCounter` to show logical grounds behind the `Key` value. You will probably not be using this particular variable (from what I see in code).

Comment: Ok i see the problem with using the `mintCounter`. But still can't find a way to select the correct index of the dictionary i want. First one will select fine and populate the combo box. but if i add another tab it blows up with same error but generates the combox for that tab but no longer will generate the combox if i select the first tab again.

Comment: @Xnub: I hope you don't generate tabs every time you click on them, right? Again, hard to help you without more details. If you feel like you need further help, please consider updating your original question. The purpose of such design would also help, if you don't mind sharing it with us.

Comment: Na it only generates a tab ever time the add file button is click. I updated the question with a bit more detail on what my program is trying to do so far.